# Varios resultados MySQL en un solo registro

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Tengo una tabla MySQL de datos de tiendas. Estas tiendas tienen uno o varios números telefónicos guardados en otra tabla y conectados mediante la foránea *id_tienda*.

Esta consulta me duplica las tiendas por cada número de teléfono que encuentra. Por lo tanto me devuelve una cantidad muy repetida de tiendas:

```sql
SELECT a.*,b.numero_telefono
FROM tiendas AS a
INNER JOIN telefonos AS b ON a.id = b.id_tienda
```

```
| id |nombre_tienda|  telefono   |
| -- |   -------   | ----------- |
|  1 | Tienda A    |   5555555   |
|  1 | Tienda A    |   6666666   |
|  1 | Tienda A    |   7777777   |
|  2 | Tienda B    |   1234567   |
|  3 | Tienda C    |   8888888   |
|  3 | Tienda C    |   9999999   |
|  4 | Tienda D    |   1111111   |
```

Lo que necesito es ajustar la consulta para que recoja *todos* los números guardados en una sola celda, respetando la cantidad de tiendas. Algo como esto:

```
| id |nombre_tienda|        telefono         |
| -- |   -------   |      ------------       |
|  1 | Tienda A    | 5555555,6666666,7777777 |
|  2 | Tienda B    |         1234567         |
|  3 | Tienda C    |     8888888,9999999     |
|  4 | Tienda D    |         1111111         |
```

Comment: Que gestor de base de datos estas usando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ocupas la función `GROUP_CONCAT()` de este modo:

```
SELECT a.id, a.nombre_tienda, GROUP_CONCAT(b.numero_telefono) AS Listado
FROM tiendas AS a
INNER JOIN telefonos AS b ON a.id = b.id_tienda
GROUP BY a.id, a.nombre_tienda;
```

*Deberás agrupar por las columnas de la tabla a, tanto `id` como `nombre_tienda`*

> La función `GROUP_CONCAT` agrupa en un mismo renglón múltples valores de un grupo de datos

- [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Perfecto! Pero aclaro: hay que usar un `GROUP BY a.id` al final de la consulta. Si no devolverá solo 1 registro. Muchas gracias!

Comment: actualmente esta función sirve? estoy intentando y no me muestra en una columna los diferentes valores